static/css/3d055d199bf4c760.css:29:22: Unknown word in next js
`npm run build

current@0.1.0 build
next build

▲ Next.js 14.2.15

Environments: .env

Creating an optimized production build ...
(node:10710) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
(node:10732) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
Failed to compile.
HookWebpackError: /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/static/css/3d055d199bf4c760.css:29:22: Unknown word
at makeWebpackError (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:312635)
at /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:106060
at eval (eval at create (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28858), :44:1)
-- inner error --
CssSyntaxError: /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/static/css/3d055d199bf4c760.css:29:22: Unknown word
at Input.error (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
at ScssParser.unknownWord (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:594:22)
at ScssParser.other (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:436:12)
at ScssParser.parse (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:471:16)
at scssParse (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
at new LazyResult (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
at Processor.process (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:48:12)
at /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:79:55
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
CssSyntaxError: /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/static/css/3d055d199bf4c760.css:29:22: Unknown word
at Input.error (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
at ScssParser.unknownWord (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:594:22)
at ScssParser.other (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:436:12)
at ScssParser.parse (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:471:16)
at scssParse (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
at new LazyResult (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
at Processor.process (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:48:12)
at /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:79:55
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)

Build failed because of webpack errors`

I executed command npm run build but resulted an unexpected error

what's at line 29 column 22 of /Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/static/css/3d055d199bf4c760.css

'/Users/pratikmishra/Desktop/current/static/css/3d055d199bf4c760.css' file doesn't exist it is generated during the process but due to the error its not generated
